# Post back is made before bootbox.confirm is called

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

My goal is to click a button and upon click show a confirm box using bootbox. If I select ok it should postback, if I click cancel it should do nothing. Currently, when I click the button it posts back before showing the confirm box, so it appears then immediately disappers.

Script

```
<script>
    function DeleteDeliverables(e,myform) {
    e.preventDefault();


    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete the selected deliverables? They will be permanently deleted", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            var deliverables = "";
            var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
                if (cbs[i].type === 'checkbox') {
                    if (cbs[i].checked) {
                        deliverables += cbs[i].value + ',';
                    }
                }
            }
            deliverables = deliverables.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
            document.getElementById("hiddenDeliverable").value = deliverables;
            myform.submit();
        }

    });

    }
</script>
```

Button

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteDeliverables(event,this.form)" /></td>
```

Postback

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeliverableManagement(string submit, DeliverableManagementModel model)
    {

         //omitted
    }
```

Comment: You would be far better changing your button to `<button type="button" id="submit">Delete</button>` and then handling its click event - `$('#submit').click(function() { ..});` and inside that, calling confirm and if true, call $('form').submit();`

Answer (score 2):

You left out the argument when you call `DeleteDeliverables()`. It should be:

```
onclick="DeleteDeliverables(event)"
```

If you check your Javascript console, you'll probably see an error because `undefined.preventDefault` is not a function. Since you're not preventing the default action, clicking on the submit button submits the form.

You also need to put

```
document.getElementById("formID").submit();
```

in the `bootbox.confirm()` callback function, since `preventDefault` prevents the normal form submission.

Finally, for that to work, you need to use a different name for the submit button. Change `name="submit"` to something like `name="submitButton"`. Otherwise, `document.getElementById("formID").submit` will refer to the button (because input names are properties of the form), not the function that submits the form.

Comment: Hmm for some reason when i did that now it doesn't submit the form when I click OK.

Comment: I was updating my answer to explain that while you were testing.

Comment: In my case where would formID be coming from? Since I dont specify an ID

Comment: `<form id="formID" ...>`

Comment: You could also pass the form as another argument to the function: `onclick="DeleteDeliverables(event, this.form)"`

Comment: Ok and if use this.form do I still need the .getElementById("formID").submit()?

Comment: I will use it as a parameter and give it a try

Comment: No, just use the argument: `formArgument.submit()`

Comment: Alright I used the argument but now, the confirm box doesn't disappear when clicking OK. See updated code. Its also maybe worth noting the button is located within a table.

Comment: Submitting the form should reload the page, I don't see how that can leave the confirm dialogue on display.

Comment: If I wanted to try it the other way where I use the document.getElementBy Id where would I specify the formid? The submit button is located in a table so should I give the table the formid name?

Comment: The table is inside a form, isn't it? The form ID has to be on the form, you can't submit a table.

Comment: I put the form tags around the table now, but now when I use the Id to submit, no reload this time.

Comment: If you don't have a form, this entire answer has been misguided. You're using AJAX in the MVC framework, and you need to do something appropriate for that. Unfortunately, I don't really know much about Twitter Bootstrap, so I can't help you there.